# What's the best way to index many-to-one relation with hibernate search?

Tags: indexing, many-to-one, hibernate-search

I have an entity with many-to-one mapping. (Product 1-* Regions, unidirectional association)

What is the best way to store index of such relation?

So it can be easily used to filter search query .

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at *@IndexedEmbedded*?